# how can I add a server to SQL management studio?

Tags: sql-server

i just installed sql management studio 2014 but the actual server does not appear, like if it is not installed at all. I already looked on services on my computer, and I looked on the SQL configuration manager under SQL server services and there are no elements.

I actually can access the management studio but i cant write anything under the sever name.

Can you tell me what i did wrong? why is there  no server?
Thanks

Comment: you need to install sql server engine also. management studio allow s you to access any sql server. if you have any other server, you can type in that server name and connect using sql management studio.

Comment: thanks radar; Im on it!

Comment: If the SQL Server runs in your own PC, then the server name can be your PC's network name, "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".